# Issues in writing multiple if conditions inside vlookup

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have two sheets.

1st sheet has an unique information in the first two columns about bike and its repair date (DD/MM/YYYY) format.

2nd sheet has multiple duplicate entries in the first three columns about bike and its repair date `(DD/MM/YYYY)` and diagnostic date `(DD/MM/YYYY)`.

Now using `vlookup`, I have find the diagnostic date, can be equal as the repair date or just before the repair date for the particular bike.

ex:-

for a bike, I have a repair date as 20/02/2017. but with three different diagnostic dates such as (21/02/2017, 27/05/2017 and 28/12/2015).

so Finally I would expect the answer as the follows:-

```
Bike     Repair date              Diagnostic date 

Name     20/02/2017                 28/12/2015
```

I was managed to do for the entries which has same year for the repair and diagnostic date.

In the prescribed example, It is different.

I would be happy If you help me on this.......

Answer (score 0):

You need `INDEX/MATCH` because it works with (composed) arrays, while `VLOOKUP` works only with ranges. The following *"array formula"* for `Sheet2!C2` (enter in C2 then type `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, then copy down in column C) uses a composed boolean array to match multiple criteria, then indexes the first successful match in column C (Diagnostic date) of Sheet1.

```
'Sheet2!C2:
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!A:A=A2)*(Sheet1!B:B=B2)*(Sheet1!C:C<=B2),0))
'Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

p.s.: it will be much faster if you limit the columns to some known upperbound on the row, i.e `C2:C1000` intead of `C:C` and the same for `B:B` and `A:A`.

Comment: Hi A.S.H, 
              It gave me the oldest diagnostic date for the particular FIN, since the condition (Repair date >= Diagnostic date) is true. But I want the diagnostic date which is closest to a specified repair date and not the oldest value.